# Shorter scope resolutions for private nested classes

Tags: c++, scope, nested-class

I have this (simplified) situation:

```
class Tree {
    class Iterator {
        class Stack {
            // ...
        }
    public:
        // ...
    }
public:
    //...
}
```

I don't want to clutter the classes' definitions and I decide to write only method declarations inside classes themselves. Later on (waaay down below) when I want to define, say, copy assignment operator like this:

```
Tree::Iterator::Stack& Tree::Iterator::Stack::operator = (const Stack& p_stack) {
// ...
}
```

I have to deal with these nasty scope resolutions. I'm wondering **if there's a way to shorten them**, because `using` and `typedef`, as I know them, don't offer me anything.

EDIT: Since this is not CodeReview, and @Yulian requested clarification, here's the short version:

I'm making an iterative Red-Black Tree implementation. Mentioned `class Iterator` is for post-order traversing (*so it's post-order-specific*), and `class Stack` is its utility class. In this short program, only `class Tree` uses the `Iterator`, and only `Iterator` uses `Stack`.

After @Yulian's reminder, I recalled that it would be way more object-oriented if the mentioned classes were separately defined (maybe even as templates), but this is a small, self contained program and I'm trying to keep it that way.

EDIT: *Self-contained* also means that it's an isolated, single-file program, so no .h files or external code re-using whatsoever. Why? *Because ACADEMIA* (and associated arbitrary restrictions).

Comment: Why doesn't `using` and `typedef` buy you anything?

Comment: They are private classes, so I can't just say `using Stack = Tree::Iterator::Stack;` or something similar - `Iterator` and `Stack` are inaccessible.

Comment: You could declare the nested class and then define its member functions in line, when you define the class later on.  But, I think that code looks fine on its own.  If you also have a bunch of namespaces to deal _inside_ the function definitions, you can actually put `using` declarations inside each function definition.

Comment: How does not nesting the classes make it any less small and self-contained?  It's probably about the same amount of code as you have already, just laid out differently.

Comment: @GuyGreer Yeees, but I'd rather not put this http://prntscr.com/922zx9 inside the definitions, if you see my point.

Comment: @StefanStanković Sorry, was that directed at the first or second comment?  If it's directed at the first (which I'm going to assume), then I understand but still don't really see your original problem as much of a problem at all.  These long names don't really clutter up the code much...

Comment: @GuyGreer On the second remark: True, it doesn't really, but I somehow only want the `Tree` public interface to be directily accessible.

Comment: To make only the Tree class accessible look up the [pimpl idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94978/discussion-between-stefan-stankovic-and-guygreer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could totally eliminate scopes resolutions with a `using` or `typedef`. But not with the traditional way because your nested classes are declared private. So you would have to use additional `using` in the `public` section of each nested class to "expose" them. Unfortunately, **this breaks the "privateness"** of them:

```
class Tree {
    class Iterator {
        class Stack {
            Stack& operator = (const Stack& p_stack);
        };
    public:
      using Stack_Out = Stack;

        // ...
    };
public:
    using Iterator_Out = Iterator::Stack_Out;
    //...

};

using Stack = Tree::Iterator_Out;

Stack& Stack::operator = (const Stack& p_stack) {
// ...
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48a32c1a992c91ee)

You could however, remove scope levels (except for the outer one, i.e., `Tree::`) with out exposing the private nested classes in the following way:

```
class Tree {
    class Iterator {
        friend class Tree;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        class Stack {
            Stack operator = (const Stack& p_stack);
        };
    public:

        // ...
    };

    using Stack = Iterator::Stack;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

public:

}; 

Tree::Stack Tree::Stack::operator = (const Stack& p_stack) {
^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a9893c7ba717d53)

Comment: Nested classes are only private if they are declared in a private section.

Comment: Doesn't this undermine the whole point of having the classes be private in the first place?

Comment: @Deduplicator in the OP they are defined in the private section.

Comment: Yes. You should insert the missing "your ... declared".

Comment: @GuyGreer yes it does unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is good to explain what you would like to achieve and way you think this method is good for your task.
IMHO, better approach is to create individual classes that are not nested and use them inside the Three class. This approach is called "HAS A". It is more clean easy to maintain and understand from others. If you provide more details we can come up with better class design.

Comment: Thanks, I've clarified the context now.

Answer (score -2):

You can let the preprocessor help you:

```
#define foobar Tree::Iterator::Stack    
foobar& foobar::operator = (const Stack& p_stack) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: As I was criticized [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110461/memory-management-for-red-black-tree), preprocessor definitions polute the world when used needlessly.

Comment: absolutely never do this.